# Line Plot Per Rolling Groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe of color, date and values. I would like to take a 2 day rolling mean of values (the column called x), grouped by color. Then plot each group as a separate line.

I have figured out how to do this by grouping, then pivoting. It works fine for this small dataset but pivot throws an error `ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow` on a large data set and to be honest it feels like an unnecessary step, so looking for an alternative way to do this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['red', '2020-01-30', 0],
                   ['red', '2020-01-31', 1],
                   ['red', '2020-02-01', 2],
                   ['blue', '2020-01-27', 3],
                   ['blue', '2020-01-28', 4],
                   ['blue', '2020-01-29', 5],
                   ['blue', '2020-01-30', 6]], 
                  columns=['color', 'date', 'x'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('color')['x'].rolling('2D').mean().reset_index()
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='color', values='x')

df.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = df.groupby('color')['x'].rolling('2D').mean().reset_index()

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='date', y='x', hue='color')
```

Or use `groupby`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for k, v in df.groupby('color'):
    v.plot(x='date', y='x', label=k, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Hi @quang-hoang, if you want to subplot each line, what would be the ideal of way doing it?